# Control NSMenuItem inset/padding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, nspopupbutton

Is it possible to control the inset or padding for `NSMenuItems`?

[image]

I.e. for a menu used in my `NSPopupButton` I'd like to remove the left padding (normally used for the checkbox) and add some padding after the text.

Can this be achieved (with public API)?

Answer (score -1):

Subclass NSPopupButtonCell and override [titleRectForBounds:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItemCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenuItemCell/titleRectForBounds:).

Set the cell to the NSPopupButton `-[NSPopupButton cell:]`

Comment: Hmm.. not a nice solution but might be the only way after all. Cheers!